# R: How to change country names in Quanteda/Newsmap?

Tags: r, dictionary, quanteda

I'm trying to do a tokens_lookup() with the Newsmap package in a 1980s computer mag from Switzerland in german. But countries had other names back then.
I need to include the sovjet union, tschechoslovakia etc. Also I need to replace all german "ß" with "ss" (We don't use ß in Switzerland.) How can I change values in a dictionary?

I have tried:

```
dic <- data_dictionary_newsmap_de
dic$EUROPE$EAST$SU <- c("sowjetunion", "udssr", "moskau")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the original dictionary in the YAML format in [Newsmap's repository](https://github.com/koheiw/newsmap/tree/master/dict), so you can edit in a text editor and load using `dictionary(file = "xxx.yml")`.

Comment: Great package by the way =)